# How do I get a binary NuGet package with one csproj's assembly but a corresponding source package with two csproj's sources?

Tags: nuget, nuget-spec

Using the really easy to follow instructions for building a NuGet package for an assembly with an associated package of sources for the symbol server, found here on David Ebbo's blog ["The easy way to publish NuGet packages with sources"](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/04/easy-way-to-publish-nuget-packages-with.html) I have indeed created a pair of packages: binary and sources.

However, the sources package is incomplete and the reason is that the sources come from two class library `.csproj` and I used ILMerge to combine the results of the second into the first. (*) So, using the minimal `.nuspec` described in this post and pointing `nuget.exe` at the `.csproj` for the "main" library, the binary package is fine, but of course the sources package only has sources for the "main" library, not also for the library that was ILMerged into the "main" library.

How do I fix this (and get the sources for *both* projects included in the symbol package but only the binary for the "main" project in the binary package)?

FYI, the actual `nuget.exe` command line was: `nuget pack CommandLineLexing.csproj -Build -Symbols -Properties Configuration=Release`.

(*) The reason I'm doing this, in case you're interested, is that the second library is a cut down version of my accumulated "C# utilities" library - you know, a bunch of extension methods and other helpers - cut down so it only has the bare minimum needed for this particular project.  And so, since it is cut down, I don't want there to be separate assembly for it which might eventually get confused with the full assembly (having the same name, and not a strong name).  So I used ILMerge to put the utilities methods into the main assembly (and also mark them internal).

Answer (score 0):

Not going to be easy I'm afraid.

NuGet [symbol packages](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package) are simply your regular package, with pdbs, augmented with source files.

Assuming you already know you can get a merged PDB with ILMerge/ILRepack (/debug), that part is probably working file, I'm assuming your issue is that only the source files from the current project gets included.

You could simply post-process your symbol.nupkg (which is a zip), and include the source files from your *other* (merged) project in the src folder (you can even try that manually).

Though if you run `srctool.exe -r MyMergedAssembly.pdb`, you'll see different root paths, where usually (for a non-merged project) they all have a common prefix.

It may work, if SymbolSource copes with having multiple path prefixes in your PDB, that I haven't tried.

I also failed to find any documentation irt to their processing of symbol packages. We can assume they use `pdbstr.exe` tool to update the PDB srcsrv section of the PDB file to redirect the symbol loading to their website, but one can only tell if they support multiple roots by testing it.

If you upload your *augmented* symbol package to symbolsource, you can download the updated PDB using a URL similar to http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public/Castle.Core.pdb/4C81FC30DF584853B9869EAB2FA7D9891/Castle.Core.pd_ (then unzip it to a pdb file)

Then you can use both `srctool.exe file.pdb` and `pdbstr.exe -r -s:srcsrv -p:file.pdb` to verify their work.